# Bulk feature flag upload to LaunchDarkly

Tags: launchdarkly

I have feature flags defined in application configuration file (JSON). Is there a way to import all the feature flags to LaunchDarkly as a bulk operation rather than creating each feature flag in the interface?

Answer (score 0):

LaunchDarkly has a REST API for creating feature flags:

https://apidocs.launchdarkly.com/tag/Feature-flags#operation/postFeatureFlag

You could write a small script to upload your flag definitions from the JSON format using the format they define in the REST API docs.

Disclaimer: I work for Statsig, a feature gating and experimentation platform